# How to convert string with comma-separated values to lwc picklist

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I am a beginner in LWC, hence please pardon for any mistakes, and would appreciate suggestions to improve. I am trying to create an LWC picklist (lightning-combobox) with options that are basically comma separated values in a Contact text field. Also, this component needs to run in the community. I also tried using getFieldValue and getFieldDisplayValue, but nothing worked. Thanks!

Contact.Test_Field__c = abc,def,ghi

Expected Output:
LWC Picklist

- abc
- def
- ghi

**HTML**

```
 <template>
        <lightning-card>
             <lightning-combobox name="progress" label="Status" value={value} 
                   placeholder="Select Progress" options={options} onchange={handleChange}> 
             </lightning-combobox>
      </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

**JS**

```
import {LightningElement, wire, } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CONTACT_ID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/User.ContactId";

    const FIELDS = [ 
    'Contact.Test_Field__c'];

    export default class lwcTest extends LightningElement {

       @wire(getRecord, { recordId:  CONTACT_ID_FIELD , fields: FIELDS })
       contact;

       //need help in this block to convert array of strings to picklist values
       get options() { 
           return this.contact.data.fields.Test_Field__c.value.split(',');
       }
        
       handleChange() {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is here: `@wire(getRecord, { recordId:  CONTACT_ID_FIELD , fields: FIELDS })`
You're passing the name of a field to `recordId` attribute, while it must be a valid id. There are few examples in the [getRecord documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record).
Due to such issue `contact.data` is undefined, so having a getter that try to read it, leads to an exception with a message like: "cannot read property of undefined ..."

Retrieving user Id is easy since LWC provides you with an appropriate module: [`@salesforce/user`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/get_current_user).
You only need to import it: `import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';`

Finally to convert comma separed values to a list of valid lightning-combobox options, you should know what attributes a picklist option must have. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/documentation) is clear about it (emphasis mine):

> In your JavaScript, define an array of options. Each option corresponds to a list item on the dropdown list. **Define the content of each option by specifying a `value` property and a `label` property**. The `label` value is displayed for the item in the rendered dropdown list, while the `value` property's value is stored when the item is selected

Since `split()` returns an array so you can leverage the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method which:

> creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

I.E.

```js
const options = csv.split(',').map((elem) => {
    const option = {
        label: elem,
        value: elem
    };
    return option;
};
```

So the LWC would look like:

```js
import {LightningElement, wire, } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CONTACT_TEST_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Contact.Test_Field__c';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';

export default class lwcTest extends LightningElement {

    userId = USER_ID;
    options = [];
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId:  '$userId' , fields: [CONTACT_TEST_FIELD] })
    fetchContact({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            const picklistValues = getFieldValue(data, CONTACT_TEST_FIELD);
            if (picklistValues) {
                this.options = picklistValues.split(',').map((elem) => {
                    const option = {
                        label: elem,
                        value: elem
                    };
                    return option;
                });
            }
        } else if (error) {
            // handle the error
        }
    }

    handleChange() {}
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you @RubenDG, for not only solving my problem but also for clearly explaining about importing userId and also for the JavaScript logic to parse the string field.

Comment: @cjprad-sfdc You're welcome. Please consider to mark helpful answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the whole community. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can read why this is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<template>
        <lightning-card>
             <lightning-combobox name="progress" label="Status" value={value} 
                   placeholder="Select Progress" options={options} onchange={handleChange}> 
             </lightning-combobox>
      </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

```js
import {LightningElement, wire, } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CONTACT_ID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/User.ContactId";

    const FIELDS = ['Contact.Test_Field__c'];

    export default class lwcTest extends LightningElement {

       @wire(getRecord, { recordId:  CONTACT_ID_FIELD , fields: FIELDS })
       contact;

       //need help in this block to convert array of strings to picklist values
       get options() { 
           //☟ the key is options will be object contains label and value.
           return this.contact.data.fields.Test_Field__c.value.split(',').map(el => {label: el, value: el});
       }
        
       handleChange() {}

}
```